# WCF error: "The X.509 certificate CN=localhost chain building failed ..."

Tags: wcf, ssl-certificate

I'm getting this error while attempting to make my WCF client and server talk to each other.

> The X.509 certificate CN=localhost chain building failed. The
>   certificate that was used has a trust chain that cannot be verified.
>   Replace the certificate or change the certificateValidationMode. A
>   certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate
>   which is not trusted by the trust.

Everything works perfectly if I turn SSL certificates off.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is a problem with your certificate (I suppose you use self-signed cert) WCF tries to verify all the chain of issuers and expects, that finally chain would end on root trusted authority. To disable that check you could add such line to app.config branch. But this "crutch" shouldn't be used in production `serviceBehaviors/behavior/serviceCredentials/clientCertificate`

```
<authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" revocationMode="NoCheck" />
```

Comment: Great, it works perfectly now. You're right, I was using a self signed cert. The other crucial trick to fix this error was to switch "NegotiateServiceCredential" to "false", in app.config, using the Microsoft Service Configuration Editor.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance - is this line supposed to go in client or server side?  And in which section of app.config?

Comment: @Shaul section is serviceBehaviors/behavior/serviceCredentials/clientCertificate You should add this to Server's app.config

Comment: This did nothing for me. I am having the same issue. Added the configuration value and it didn't change anything.

Comment: I solved the problem adding on the client configuration file (app.config) an Endpoint Behavior and on the serverCertificate I set the CertificateValidationMode to None. Don't forget to reference the Endpoint Behavior on the end point main configuration in order to take into account the behavior

Answer (score 41):

I fixed the problem by turning off validation in my code like this:

```
client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = 
System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
```

Where `client` is an instance of my service reference.

Comment: this did the trick for me too, changing the web.config didn't. Please note that this should never make it into your production environment!

Comment: Had to add reference "System.IdentityModel" to client project to make it compile

Comment: The X509CertificateValidationMode enum is located in the System.IdentityModel assembly. This is confusing because the X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication class seems to be located in System.ServiceModel.dll.

Answer (score 9):

The correct thing to do is to [setup your own Dev/Test Trusted Root Certificate](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24027/SSL-with-Self-hosted-WCF-Service) and sign your client and service certificates with this.

Bypassing chain trust in your Dev/Test environment may "work" but your Dev/Test environment is now configured differently to Production, which is not a great idea as you may find some tests produce false positives or false negatives.

Answer (score 4):

Add endpoint behavior in your client application(e.g:App.config) and set the behavior configuration you added in the endpoint.

```
 <behaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="certificateEndpointBehavior">
              <clientCredentials>
                <serviceCertificate>             
                  <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" revocationMode="NoCheck"/>
                </serviceCertificate>
                </clientCredentials>      
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

<endpoint address="http://localhost/Invoice.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"  bindingConfiguration="WsHttpBinding_ACKS" contract="Invoice" name="Invoice"
       behaviorConfiguration="certificateEndpointBehavior" >

</endpoint>
```

Comment: This is the right solution.  You don't even need to worry about setting the 'certificateValidationMode'.  Only the revocation mode is needed.  Setting the values on the server side do not work.  Hacking every client endpoint in code is far too much work.

Answer (score 3):

I had some difficulty with this same exact issue. I was using the CustomToken-VS2010 sample from the WIF SDK.

The sample doesn't have an app.config and I felt that knowing how the code works is useful anyway, so I spent some time investigating this. I feel I should show my results here. I hope this inforamation is helpful.

I had the same issue. The problem I had was "where do I set this mode?" I had a difficult time finding the object that had this property to set that was actually the correct object. I finally found it as part of the **ChannelFactory**:

```
using System.ServiceModel.Security;
:
ChannelFactory<IEcho> echoChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IEcho>(...)
echoChannelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
```

So, the place to set this is in the ChannelFactory object.

Running Visual Studio 2010 as local administrator, I was able to get the sample to work (after having also run the batch file associated with all the samples to create the certificate, etc.)

Again, ***this is not something you would do in a production environment***, but knowing how to set the service certificate authentication mode is probably a pretty good thing to know overall.

Comment: Whether `ChannelFactory<TChannel>.Credentials` or `ClientBase<TChannel>.ClientCredentials` should be used depends on whether you are explicitly using a channel factory (with dynamic proxy) or the generated proxy that was created by some code generator (e.g. by adding a service reference via the VS-GUI).

Answer (score 3):

When deactivating the revocationMode helped, then most likely you are missing a *client revocation list* for your root CA.

```
makecert -crl -n "CN=CARoot" -r -sv CARoot.pvk CARoot.crl
```

This also needs to be imported to the trusted root certification authorities. See also [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47677353/2243584).

Answer (score 0):

(Thought i would share this just in case it saves somebody out there some time) I ran into into this issue while running a web application on WIF. I fixed my problem by moving a copy of the x.509 certificate i was working with from "Certificates/personal/certificates" folder to "Trusted Root Certification Authorities/Certificates" Folder inside the certificate store. You can do this by running microsoft management console

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Aseiu's comment above, I found that the exact same error above will be output when the cert is missing from the trusted store in the server. In researching into the issue, I also found that by looking at the event viewer under Windows Logs/Application will contain an error that details the certificate that it is having a problem with. You can also correlate the activity log with the entries in the SVC log for the service.