# Self Signed Certificate and CertificateValidationMode on Windows XP only

Tags: .net, wcf, x509certificate, self-signed

All my code is .Net 4.0.

I have wcf service using certificate+username/password authentication. In my service I used a self signed certificate, so the public key loaded to client should go to `Trusted People` store. I am aware of that.

I use a channel factory to open the connection.  My code looks like:

```
    public static ChannelFactory<T> CreateMyServiceClientChannel<T>(string serviceUrl, string serviceUsername, string servicePassword)
    {
        NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
        binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Windows;
        binding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
        binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;

        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPeople, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = store.Certificates.OfType<X509Certificate2>().FirstOrDefault(cert => cert.Subject == "CN=MyServicesCert");
        store.Close();

        // Instantiate the EndPointAddress using the Service URL, endpoint identity
        Uri baseAddress = new Uri(serviceUrl);
        EndpointIdentity epi = EndpointIdentity.CreateX509CertificateIdentity(clientCertificate);
        EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(baseAddress, epi);

        // Create the Channel Factory instance using binding and end point variables. 
        ChannelFactory<T> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<T>(binding, endpoint);

        // set credentials
        channelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = serviceUsername;
        channelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = servicePassword;

        channelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;

        // Return the channel factory
        return channelFactory;
    }
```

The question here is the 2nd to last statement:

```
channelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
```

In my Windows 7 machine I don't have to include it, and I can communicate with service properly. However in Windows XP machine, if I don't include it I got exception

> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: SOAP
>   security negotiation with 'net.tcp://my-server:20800/my-service.svc'
>   for target 'net.tcp://my-server:20800/my-service.svc' failed. See
>   inner exception for more details. --->
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenValidationException: The
>   X.509 certificate CN=MyServicesCert chain building failed. The
>   certificate that was used has a trust chain that cannot be verified.
>   Replace the certificate or change the certificateValidationMode. A
>   certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate
>   which is not trusted by the trust provider.

So it looks like .net behaves differently between Windows 7 and XP, how is that?

Comment: Are you sure the self-signed certificate is in the trusted certificates on the Win XP machine?

Comment: What happens when you set it to `PeerTrust`?

Comment: Try [this suggestion][1]: Set revocationMode="NoCheck".


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256520/wcf-error-the-x-509-certificate-cn-localhost-chain-building-failed

Comment: @Jay PeerTrust also works.

Comment: @gtrig the public key is in `trusted people` as my code uses.