# Trustchain error NetTcpBinding with message (username) security

Tags: wcf, authentication, message, nettcpbinding

After a week(!) of searching, I hope someone is able to tell me what I'm doing wrong.

I keep on getting the following error message:

> The X.509 certificate CN=localhost chain building failed. The certificate that was used has a trust chain that cannot be verified. Replace the certificate or change the certificateValidationMode.

To start from the beginning. This is my code/config serverside:

```
ServiceHost svcHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestService));          

// Enable metadata publishing.
ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = svcHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
if (smb == null)
    smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
svcHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

ServiceDebugBehavior sdb = svcHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
if (sdb == null) { sdb = new ServiceDebugBehavior(); svcHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(sdb); }
sdb.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;

// Meta data servicepoint
svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName, MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "mex");

// Credentials          
CustomUserNamePasswordValidator clientAuthenticationValidator = new TCustomUserNamePasswordValidator();
svcHost.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode = UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom;
svcHost.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator = (UserNamePasswordValidator) clientAuthenticationValidator;

// Certificate
svcHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2("TestServer.pfx", "password");        
svcHost.Credentials.IssuedTokenAuthentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.ChainTrust;
svcHost.Credentials.IssuedTokenAuthentication.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.None;
svcHost.Credentials.IssuedTokenAuthentication.TrustedStoreLocation = StoreLocation.LocalMachine;

// Binding
NetTcpBinding netTcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
netTcpBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;            
netTcpBinding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
netTcpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
netTcpBinding.ReliableSession.Enabled = true;
svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITestService), netTcpBinding, "");

svcHost.Open();
```

With the following app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="TestService">
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/" />
                        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9595" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>      
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The following commands I used to get the certificates:
**Root CA:**

> makecert.exe -n "CN=TestCA" -r -pe -a sha512 -len 4096 -cy authority -sr LocalMachine -ss Root -sv TestCA.pvk TestCA.cer
>   pvk2pfx.exe -pvk TestCA.pvk -spc TestCA.cer -pfx TestCA.pfx -po aaaaa

**Service:**

> makecert.exe -n "CN=localhost" -iv TestCA.pvk -ic TestCA.cer -pe -a sha512 -len 4096 -b 12/14/2014 -e 01/01/2020 -sky exchange -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -sv TestServer.pvk TestServer.cer
>   pvk2pfx.exe -pvk TestServer.pvk -spc TestServer.cer -pfx TestServer.pfx -po aaaaa

Where I imported TestCA.cer in Trusted Root CA and, as shown in code, the pfx file is used as servicecertificate.

As far as I understood, I do not have to give a certificate for the client, since it uses username credentials to authenticate itself, where the servicecertificate is used for ssl.
As said, as soon as I start up the client and call a function, I get the above exception.

I already tried to attach the TestServer certificate to the 9595 port with netsh. I run both client and service on the same computer.

I truly hope someone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues is most likely caused by a self-signed certificate that is not “trusted” by the client.  In order to accommodate this scenario, you have a few options:

1. Import the self-signed certificate into the client machine’s
   “Trusted People” store.
2. Follow the MSDN guidance to [Create and Install Temporary Certificates in WCF for Message Security During Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647171.aspx)
3. Update the client software to bypass the certificate verification check as defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256520/wcf-error-the-x-509-certificate-cn-localhost-chain-building-failed).

Comment: After remaking the certificates according to the link provided in 2. and used netsh to add the ssl certificates to both port 8080 and 9595, it finally worked. I'm a little amazed at myself not being able to find that link. Thanks a lot, Seymour!